# Firebase Security Rules permission denied

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My firebase database is something like this:-

[image]

these are the security rules i have written but when i use them in simulator they validate just fine, but when used in code, give permission denied error

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jokes" : {
      "textjokes" : {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
  }
},
  "users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
  }
},
 "userslikelist": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
  }
}
}
```

}

I get error:-

/userslikelist/qzCqJph6XcZbiIpbDKTTxwjRHrh1/-KK850oXwPnOvxan1xNG failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied

/jokes/textjokes/MISC-0-01/likeCount failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied

My code:-

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/userslikelist/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(!likedMap.containsKey(postSnapshot.getKey())){
                    likedMap.put(postSnapshot.getKey(), postSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I dont get it. what am i doing wrong?

Updated Code:-

```
{
    "rules": {
        "jokes": {
            "textjokes": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": "auth != null"
            }
        },
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
            }
        },
        "userslikelist": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who is having this problem. The issue here was that i was using the legacy firebase api methods to set values and read from database. I changed the method of updating to use the new google firebase system as used in this example and now i can update the database.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/NewPostActivity.java#L39-L39

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving read access to `/userslikelist/userId` so you wont be able to get `dataSnapshot` on your `onDataChange`.

Make sure to set a read permission on the `/userslikelist/userId` level.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jokes" : {
      "textjokes" : {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "userslikelist": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid", //do whatever logic you need here
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: i gave read = true to "userslikelist" node but still nothing. Same error

Comment: Show your updated code/rules please, because this was definitely an error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated rules. Pls check

Comment: With those rules the first write should succeed. You can probably find out why it's still failing by running it the simulator, which you can find in Console > Database > Rules > Simulator.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The simulator is giving me successful results but when i run in code, the error comes